# how to replace routing path in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular5, angular6, angular-routing

**base path is - **

> http://localhost:2000/matchcenter/cricket

when I click to **load another page** by clicking to menue my **route becomes**

> http://localhost:2000/matchcenter/cricket/football

***and I get error***

> ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.
>   URL Segment: 'matchcenter/cricket/football' Error: Cannot match any
>   routes. URL Segment: 'matchcenter/cricket/football'

**html**

```
  <mat-tab *ngFor="let item of navLinks" >


                <div routerLink="{{item.path}}">{{item.label}}</div>

            </mat-tab>
```

**ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CricketComponent } from '../cricket/cricket.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.scss']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  navLinks:any;

  constructor() {
    this.navLinks=[
      {path:'cricket',label: 'Cricket'},
      {path:'football',label: 'Football'},
      {path:'nba',label: 'NBA'},
    ]
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { MatchcenterComponent } from './matchcenter/matchcenter.component';
import { FleshScreenComponent } from './flesh-screen/flesh-screen.component';
import { CricketComponent } from './cricket/cricket.component'
const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '' , component: FleshScreenComponent, pathMatch:'full' },
 { path: 'login' , component:LoginComponent },
 { path: 'register' , component: RegisterComponent },
 { path: 'error' , component: ErrorComponent},
 { path: 'matchcenter' , component: MatchcenterComponent},
 { path: 'matchcenter/cricket' , component: CricketComponent},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Your base path is - ** ????

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#configuration

Comment: <base href="/">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First things first make sure your routes start from `/`

```
this.navLinks=[
    { path:'/cricket',label: 'Cricket'},
    { path:'/football',label: 'Football'},
    { path:'/nba',label: 'NBA'},
];
```

Based on my assumption I guess you want to pass [route param](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route) to your `matchcenter` route. Where `cricket` `football` `nba` are dynamic params given to `matchcenter` route.

To do so make following changes in your route

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '' , component: FleshScreenComponent, pathMatch:'full' },
    { path: 'login' , component:LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register' , component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'error' , component: ErrorComponent},
    { path: 'matchcenter/:type' , component: MatchcenterComponent}
];
```

You can further get the passed params in `MatchcenterComponent` using angular `ActivatedRoute`.

Or else if you dont want route params. You need to define all routes in the routing module. For current scenario you can use

```
const routes: Routes = [
    { path: '' , component: FleshScreenComponent, pathMatch:'full' },
    { path: 'login' , component:LoginComponent },
    { path: 'register' , component: RegisterComponent },
    { path: 'error' , component: ErrorComponent},
    { path: 'matchcenter' , component: MatchcenterComponent},
    { path: 'matchcenter/cricket' , component: CricketComponent},
    { path: 'matchcenter/football' , component: FootballComponent},
    { path: 'matchcenter/nba' , component: NbaComponent},
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Paths need to start with a forward slash ( **`/`** )

Try changing the path configs to this:

```
{
  path: '/cricket',
  label: 'Cricket'
}, {
  path: '/football',
  label: 'Football'
}, {
  path: '/nba',
  label: 'NBA'
},
```

Comment: Using your way I am getting 
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'football'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'football'

Comment: @TestingAnurag, can you please add the routing config to your question as well?

Comment: I have added please see

Answer (score 0):

create something like that:

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="" [routerLink]="['/datatable']">datatable</a></li>
    <li><a href="" [routerLink]="['/customer']">Customer</a></li>
    <li><a href="" [routerLink]="['/courses']">Courses</a></li>
    <li><a href="" [routerLink]="['/my-table']">MyTable</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I think you miss the "/" Behined Your path string.

Answer (score -1):

Your `routerLink="{{item.path}}"` in your html should be `routerLink="['/matchcenter/{{item.path}}']"`. The `/` in front makes it go from baseroute.

Comment: using your way I am getting error 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'matchcenter/football'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'matchcenter/football'

Comment: Don't mix square brackets and double curly brackets, they just do the same thing. So Angular will try to re-parse it as if it was javascript

Comment: @TestingAnurag That is because you don't have a route for football in your `app-routing.module`. If you want `http://localhost:2000/matchcenter/football` to work you have to add a route in the `app-routing.module` like ` { path: 'matchcenter/football' , component: FootballComponent},`.